# install Quarto template from private Github repository?

Tags: quarto

I created a private repository. In RStudio, when I run quarto use template username/quarto-template, I get

## ERROR: download failed (HTTP status 404 - Not Found)

It works fine if I change it to a public repository.

Is there a way to have RStudio download from a private repository?